# Named Credential shows Authentication Status Pending even after successful authentication

Tags: apex, callout, oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I am trying to setup oAuth between salesforce and Workday. I created a Auth provider and a named credential as shown in the screenshots.
[Named credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIcqU.png)]
[Auth Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve40J.png)

- I checked 'Start Authentication Flow on Save' while saving the named credential.
- On save, I was redirected to Workday page for authentication.
- On entering my workday username and password, I could login successfully to workday. I was not redirected back to salesforce. Should I be?
- But the Named credential still shows a authentication status of 'Pending'.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check once Authorize Endpoint URL And Token Endpoint URL
If it is the case, you need to verify that the Token Endpoint URL is 100% exact (it will not work with the smallest typo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating workday app with the salesforce auth provider callback url resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Click on Edit and you will see a checkbox mark as true and it will redirect you the login page. enter and then you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: I already did that. I checked 'Start Authentication Flow on Save' while saving the named credential. On save, I was redirected to Workday page for authentication. On entering my workday username and password, I could login successfully to workday. But the Named credential still shows a authentication status of 'Pending'.

Comment: Are you sure the callback URL is correct?

Comment: The callback url is autogenerated on saving the auth provider.